# What is wrong with this c language code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, void

I've written this code to permute any number and the following error appears:
In function 'int main()':
invalid use of void expression

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long int uint;   
uint t[11],n;

void permute(uint k) {      
   uint i,c;

  if (1==k) {    
     for (i=n; i>0; --i)

     printf("%d", t[i]);  
     printf("\n"); 
  } 
  else 
  {    
    permute(k-1);   
    for (i=1; i<k; ++i)
    {   
      c=t[i]; t[i]=t[k]; t[k]=c;    
      permute(k-1);    
      c=t[i]; t[i]=t[k]; t[k]=c;}
    }
 }

 void run(uint x)
 {    
    n=0;
    while (x>0)
    {    
       t[++n]=x%10;    
       x /= 10;
    }    
    permute(n);
}

int main () 
{  
    printf ("%d\n",run(125)); 
}
```

Comment: Please format for readability! TIA

Answer (score 3):

```
printf ("%d\n",run(125));
```

You are using the return value of function `run` but `run` returns nothing

```
void run(uint x)
```

`void` means the function returns nothing,

Answer (score 1):

You have declared run as `void run( uint x)` but you are passing it as the argument to `printf()` which would expect it to return an integer value in order to match the `"%d\n"` format string.

Answer (score 0):

`run` returns `void` and you can't "extract" an integer from the function `run` when it is not returning any value. This is invalid.